# Trouble with kitchen pull-out faucet universal hose?

Tags: kitchens, leak, faucet, kitchen-sink, hose

([I am using terms as shown in this exploded view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD3bV.jpg))

A few months back the hose for my kitchen pull-out faucet broke. I went to the home improvement store and bought a universal replacement hose. I had no trouble connecting the hose to the faucet base, and there are no leaks there.

However, I have had endless trouble with leaks at the end of the hose that connects to the pull-out spray head. I believe this is because I am unable to get the retaining clip (c-clip) into the right groove in the hose stem.

Please see the pictures below showing the hose and the slide nut for the spray head. As far as I can tell, the trouble is that the slide nut is too "tall" and the hose stem does not protrude far enough out to allow me to slip the c-clip into the retaining groove. This causes the hose to slide out slightly and leak water out of the slide nut.

Does my conclusion seem right to you? How should I solve this? I've tried wrapping the hose stem with teflon tape to create a tighter seal, but it lasts a couple weeks at the most. Do I need a specific hose for this spray head (Moen)? My home improvement store only has two universal hoses, and both have the exact same hose stem.

Do I need a new spray head entirely? That may be difficult to find one that matches the existing faucet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Compare to [this image](https://cdn2.tmbi.com/TFH/Step-By-Step/display/FH06JUN_SINKSP_02.JPG), which shows the c-clip retaining groove well above the slide nut.

Comment: Is there a spacer inside the outer fitting which is preventing the hose from fitting deeper into the fitting and so protruding far enough to get the spring clip on in the right groove?

Comment: So you got a new "universal" hose, but and are fitting this into the old nozzle/strainer assembly? How does the end of the plastic hose compare to the old one?